# Local expression of Hessian operator in Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hessian-matrix

Define the Hessian of a differentiable function $F \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold by 
$$(\nabla^2 F)(X,Y) = X(Y(F)) - (\nabla_X Y)(F)$$
where $\nabla$ is the connection on $M$.

> If $(U, \varphi = (x^1, \dots , x^n)$ is a system of local coordinates in a neighborhood $U$ of $M$, denoting $\nabla^2 F = F_{ij}dx^i dx^j$, how are the components $F_{ij}$ relate to the function $F$ and the Christoffer symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ of the connection?

If we denote $X = X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$  and $Y = Y^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$, then 
$$Y(F) = Y^j \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}$$
so 
$$X(Y(F)) = X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial F^2}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}$$
or that's what I think. However, I'm not sure how the expression $(\nabla_X Y)(F)$ translates into local coordinates. Some help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how is the christoffel symbols defined?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes! We have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Gamma_{ij}^k = \nabla_{\partial /\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$, right?

Comment: @JohnMa Well, I think we could exploit linearity of $\nabla$ there if we start with $\nabla_{X^i \partial}{\partial x^i}Y^i \frac{\partal}{\partial x^j}$, but I'm not really sure what $(\nabla_X Y)(F)$ means, if it's $\nabla_X Y(f)$ or something else...

Comment: $\nabla_X Y$ is a vector field, so $(\nabla_XY)(F)$ is just the directional derivative along that direction. Just like the term $YF$.

Comment: @JohnMa So would it just be $\nabla_{X^i \partial /\partial x^i}Y^j \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}$?